# To die or to kill?

Tags: lyrics

In the Boney M song '[Ma Baker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLzqMJQzzcA)', one line is:

> But she knew how to die

I always wondered if this is correct English, or that it should be:

> But she knew how to kill

Since dying seems to relate to oneself?

Comment: Was *she* a murderer? (Sorry, am at work, and cannot check youtube.)

Comment: @Neeku Yes, but I just saw that according to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma_Barker) she died during a gunfight with the FBI. So it could be that the lyrics refer to that event. Nonetheless it still sounds weird.

Comment: Ma Baker and her sons...
They didn't want to hang...
They died with blazing guns...
And so the story ends...
Of one who left no friends...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always understood the lyrics to be about her dying, that is, the end of *her life*:

Her death was quite a spectacular event, a shoot-out that took hours. It certainly did something to augment the legend of ma Barker as a hardened criminal. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma_Barker#Death) says the following:

> Agents surrounded the house at 13250 East Highway C-25 on the morning of January 16, 1935. Unknown to the FBI, Karpis and other gang members had left three days before, leaving only Fred and Ma in the house. Ordered to surrender, Fred opened fire; both he and his mother were killed by federal agents after an intense, hours-long gun-battle. Allegedly, many local people came to watch the events unfolding, even holding picnics during the gun battle. After gunfire ceased coming from the house, the FBI ordered local estate-handyman Willie Woodbury to enter the house wearing a bullet-proof vest. Woodbury reported that there was no-one inside alive.

Comment: +1 'What a way to go', much better than hanging or the electric chair or whatever was in store for her. Live by the sword ...